# d3/chrome click/zoom bug?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, d3.js

I think there is a bug in either d3 or Chrome, but more than likely I'm doing something wrong.

I have something like

```
d3.select("body").append("svg")
  [...]
  .on("click", function() { /* stuff */ })
  .call(zoom);
```

with

```
var zoom = d3.zoom()
  [...]
  .on("zoom", function() { /* stuff */ });
```

Now, this works fine, *most of the time*. Click is being handled, and zoom is being handled.

Sometimes, Chrome will just stop processing click altogether. I've put some debugging `console.log()`'s in there and I've found the the `"zoom"` event on the `zoom` object is being called rather than the `"click"` event on the `svg` object. A refresh won't fix the problem. I actually have to exit my browser completely and relaunch, and then it works fine again for a while.

I haven't noticed this happening in Edge or Firefox, but since my main browser is Chrome, I haven't really tested it in the other browsers for long enough to determine if it is or isn't happening there too.

I was convinced I was doing something wrong until I checked the example at https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/35964711079355050ff1 which also appears to have the same problem, and works fine after restarting my browser.

I'm using d3 4.4.0 and I have Chrome 55.0.2883.87.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is ancient, but I was having this issue and updated to d3 4.13.0 and I believe it is now mitigated.